# How enable gzip compression on GoDaddy shared windows hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compression, gzip

I have done research on enabling gzpi compression on GoDaddy shared windoes hosting and here is the proposed solution:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>

  </system.webServer>
```

But this is currently not working and I am not getting http response header, Content-Encoding   gzip.

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you restart the application pool after updating the web.config?

Answer (score 1):

Adding that to my Web.Config allowed my Godaddy site to compress aspx page responses.  But to compress ASMX WebService responses, I had to additionally add this to Global.asax:

```
void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var app = sender as HttpApplication;
    var acceptEncoding = app.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
    var prevUncompressedStream = app.Response.Filter;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding))
    {
        acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToLower();
        if (acceptEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
        {
            app.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(prevUncompressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
            app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        }
    }
    Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = true;
}
```